# Replacing &ndash; character using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace the dash in a title on by site with a span tag and line break to break to title over two lines.
Unfortunately I don't have access to do this in the PHP :(

The below statement seems to do this. Although with bugs as it's making this change to the character throughout the page.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u2013/g, "</span><br /><span>");
```

The jQuery solution I tried below, works but sometimes the element would have a visibility hidden on the element!

```
$("#events h3 a").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\u2013/g,"</span><br /><span>"));
});
```

Ideally I would like to use the pure JavaScript version above but need help navigating to the Events Link.

```
#events h3 a
```

Thanks anybody who can help, I have hunted for a solution everywhere.

This is an example of the page structure. And explains why the span close and start are back to front in the code excerpt. This is so each half can be styled when on separate lines.

```
<ul id="events">
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>First Events Title - On Every Sunday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>Second Events Title - On Every Monday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe try with `<span><br /><span/>` instead of `</span><br /><span>`

Comment: Apologies mdmullinax I should have put a page structure excerpt in to explain why these are back to front. I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: _What_ would have a visibility hidden property on it?  Why does that matter?  Why do you need two spans rather than just one with a `<br />` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems so simple, is this a trick question? If it as simple as i thought try this.

```
$(function () {
    $("#events h3 a").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().split(" - ").join("</span><br/><span>"));
    });
});
```

Comment: when I replaced the - for the /\u2013/g this worked perfectly. All fixed, thanks for your help. For some reason when I navigated away and back to the page with my solution (attempt) the span content was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('events').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you do the special encoding in your regex (maybe something I am missing). Anyway, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Je326/6/) works

```
$("#events h3 a span").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace("-","</span><br /><span>"));
});
```

Comment: for some reason this did'nt work most likely because of how the CMS is outputting the - Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using u002d instead of u2013.

```
$("#events h3 a").each(function() {
  $(this)
      .html($(this)
                .html()
                .replace(/\u002d/g, "<span /><br /><span>"));
});
```

[updated JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwv4/6/)

**Update**

Interestingly u002d refers to ASCII hyphen and u2013 refers to the en dash. It appears "-" is [seen as the ASCII hyphen](http://jsfiddle.net/btWur/1/), and not as the en dash. Honestly, it's quite confusing since they look alike :-S.

Here's a [web page](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/) for the special characters for commonly confused with, like hyphen and en dash.

So, I've updated the code, replacing "-" with "& # x2013" [SO sanitizes my entry :)] in the html and it will work as you expected.

```
<ul id="events">
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>First Events Title &#x2013 On Every Sunday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>Second Events Title &#x2013 On Every Monday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Unicode version](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwv4/7/)

Alternately, you may use "& ndash ;" [Again, SO sanitizes my entry] instead of the Unicode form

```
<ul id="events">
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>First Events Title &ndash; On Every Sunday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <span>Second Events Title &ndash; On Every Monday</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[ndash'ed version](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwv4/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your research and help

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, if you think this one is the answer, kindly tag it ;).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript way to do it

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/dnUgF/)

```
var replaceDashes = function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    // copied an &ndash; character to use in the replace
    body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/ – /g, '</span><br /><span>');
};
replaceDashes();
```